# Input placeholder text-transform CSS styling

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder, css

Is it somehow possible to use CSS text-transform for input's placeholder? I've tried pseudo elements:

```
.user_info input ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
 text-transform:none;
}
.user_info input :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
 text-transform:none;
}
.user_info input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
text-transform:none;
}
.user_info input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
text-transform:none;
}
```

But it seems, that it works only in Mozilla. Maybe do you know any workarounds?

Comment: take a look at this, which will work for Chrome as well, but for IE it is not going to work, and you probably need to do some js stuff for implementing it yourself: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css

Comment: It works in Chrome as well but you'll need to remove the space between `.user_info input` and `::-webkit-input-placeholder` - http://jsfiddle.net/t5SU6/ - not sure about IE though.

Comment: Your code works in chrome too. Are you sure you're implementing it correctly?

Comment: As @Adrift posted, the problem was that additional space between input and colons. Honestly, wouldn't thought that it could be a cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is how bootstrap handles it (and has worked well for me on my uses and tests):

```
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
```

You have some syntax issues that @Adrift noted, here is a recommended fix:  `input.user_info::-webkit-input-placeholder {`